# Programs Icons of WineHQ

Tags: wine, microsoft-office

Just installed Office 2010 in my ubuntu x64 and run smooth but now I have an stetic issue dash and synapse can find the office applications :) but all the office apps are shown with the wine icon.

I change it manually with an icon pack at the wine folder but still with wine icons.

So any idea to do this??

Answer (score 2):

From what I can deduce, it seems your problem lies with custom applications in `~/.local/share/applications`.

Simply clear this folder: `rm -rf ~/.local/share/applications/*/*` and it should be all good.

Please note that your applications will now not show up again. I would suggest removing them from Wine, and installing them with [PlayOnLinux](https://askubuntu.com/questions/233782/how-does-one-install-playonlinux). This application will ensure that you get the correct icons (though in your launcher under Unity they will still show with Wine icons).