# How does one install PlayOnLinux?

Tags: installation, wine, playonlinux

How do I install PlayOnLinux on Ubuntu?

Comment: I haven't tried, but this refers to the one in Ubuntu Software Center?

Comment: @EODCraftStaff I haven't checked, but I'm assuming yes. At the time this question was written, it wasn't so simple and straightforward.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### Installing from the Ubuntu repository:

PlayOnLinux is available from the default Ubuntu repositories on Ubuntu versions 12.04 and later.
Install it with

```
sudo apt-get install playonlinux
```

Then click **➕ Install a program** in PlayOnLinux and search for the Windows program that you want to install.

[image]

However, if you want the latest version, you will need to add the PlayOnLinux repository.

### Installing from the PlayOnLinux repository:

#### The following example is for Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

```
wget -q "http://deb.playonlinux.com/public.gpg" -O- | sudo apt-key add -
sudo wget http://deb.playonlinux.com/playonlinux_precise.list -O /etc/apt/sources.list.d/playonlinux.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install playonlinux
```

If you want to ensure that you have the correct repo for your version of Ubuntu, or only want to install from the .deb file, you can check here: http://www.playonlinux.com/en/download.html

Comment: Related, and pertinent for many applications running in PlayOnLinux which have menus too small to comfortably see: How to change menu and text sizes in GUI windows running in Wine on PlayOnLinux: https://askubuntu.com/questions/310089/how-to-change-default-font-size-in-menus-after-wine/1097341#1097341