# Proper installation method for play on linux

Tags: software-installation

how long does it take to install play on linux via the terminal? I got as far as the end user agreement and nothing has happened past that

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/233782/how-does-one-install-playonlinux
Use this for installation.

Comment: I typed in sudo apt-get install playonlinux then it asked for my password then it ran line after line of code til it got to the end user agreement.It says package configuration now. Should I just wait?

Comment: Yeah, some packages take a while...

Comment: Ok thanks for your help.Ill just leave it alone then. It says in red at the top configuring ttf-msccorefonts so I guess that’s taking a while

Comment: I mean it says configuring ttf-mscorefonts-installer

Answer (score 0):

`playonlinux` is now in [Official ubuntu Repository](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/playonlinux) . You can install `playonlinux` with its dependencies as:

```
sudo apt-get install playonlinux binutils bzip2 cabextract curl gettext-base gnupg icoutils imagemagick mesa-utils netcat p7zip-full python python-wxgtk2.8 unzip wget wine x11-utils xterm
```

Comment: I did that and got as far as the microsoft end user agreement and nothing more has happened...I was just worried I screwed something up but I guess the terminal is still working on it