# Install wxPython on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: package-management, software-installation, python

I'm trying to install wxPython on Ubuntu 16.04. I'm aware of [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/758774/how-to-install-wxpython-ubuntu-16-04) question and related answer. In particular, if I run a .py file that uses wxPython python3: `wxPython_HelloWorld.py` (copy-pasted from the [introductory page to wxPython](https://wiki.wxpython.org/Getting%20Started))

I get the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "wxPython_HelloWorld.py", line 2, in <module>
    import wx
ImportError: No module named 'wx'
```

But python-wxgtk3.0 is installed. Indeed, running the installation command `sudo apt-get install python-wxgtk3.0` returns:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
python-wxgtk3.0 is already the newest version (3.0.2.0+dfsg-1build1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 79 not upgraded.
```

Does anybody have a guess about what the problem could be?

Comment: Why don't you start by upgrading those 79 packages with `sudo apt-get upgrade` ?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The solution was a different one, but this is indeed something that should have been done!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to run the following Python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import wx
app = wx.App(False)
frame = wx.Frame(None, wx.ID_ANY, "Hello World") 
frame.Show(True) 
app.MainLoop()
```

The Python used for the REPL is not the same as the version of Python the script is being run in ( `python` ). In particular I was able to duplicate the error in your question with python3 as follows:

```
python3
>>> import wx
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'wx'
```

The solution was to run the script in Python 2.x, which in my Ubuntu 16.04 is Python 2.7.12.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is precisely the case. Indeed, trying to install wxPython via pip gives `Requirement already satisfied: wxpython in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-3.0-gtk2
` . And the package is therefore installed for python2.7. Now the question becomes how to use wxPython in combination with python3. But I'll try to solve it by myself.

Comment: I got wxPython phoenix for python3 by running the command:
`sudo pip3 install -U --pre \
        -f https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/snapshot-builds/linux/gtk3/ubuntu-16.04 \
        wxPython_Phoenix` which I got by browsing the official page https://wxpython.org/.