# Wine nor winetricks show up on applications menu

Tags: wine, 16.10, winetricks

I have installed and uninstalled wine and reinstalled it several times but it never shows up in the Applications menu. I was able to install with wine using terminal, but the program does not show up in the menu. I have tried about everything I can find searching the above title, but haven't found a fix.

Comment: I guess it's because wine isn't meant to be started on it's own. It needs command-line options to know what to do. If you want a graphical UI to wine you might be interested using [playonlinux](http://askubuntu.com/questions/233782/how-does-one-install-playonlinux)

Comment: playonlinux was part of the install.

Comment: This was in a new install of Ubuntu 16.10, I had to install 16.04 instead to get things to work.  There were a lot of problems I was finding I had with the newer 16.10 download.  Now Wine is working and showing up where it should.  with older version of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Wine is used to launch EXEs, so it has no point being in the menu.  When running EXEs, Wine will open them.  As far as Winetricks, just run 'winetricks' in the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

This does not work if wxmaxima is installed.  Ubuntu sends .exe files to wxmaxima instead of wine, wine does not show up on the "open with other" list, and there is no browse option. bummer.