# How do I download photoshop illustrator in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: adobe, websites

I'm planning to design a web page for my project. So can anyone help me how can i install through the terminal. Or do I've any alternative.
Thank you!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does one install PlayOnLinux?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/233782/how-does-one-install-playonlinux)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First download the illustrator setup file, then just go to **Ubuntu Software Center** and install the **PlayOnLinux** software, It has got many software for your OS.
Or use this command to install it

```
sudo apt-get install playonlinux
```

Then launch PlayOnLinux and click **Install**, wait for refresh then select **Adobe Illustrator CS6**, click **Install** and follow wizard instructions.

[image: click here to view an image of the PlayOnLinux window]