# GTA Vice City requires Directx 8.1 - how can I run it?

Tags: wine, games

[image]
Does anyone know how to run this game "GTA Vice City" on Ubuntu? I kept getting Directx 8.1 error when I run the game. I have also installed the latest version of Wine.

I also facing the same issues when running GTA San Andreas!
I use this code below force run directx 9 and it shows blue screen.

```
wine '/home/user/.wine/gtavc/gta-vc.exe' -applaunch 220 -dxlevel 90
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does one install PlayOnLinux?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/233782/how-does-one-install-playonlinux)

Comment: on PlayonLinux I see many games but I did not see gta vice city, I'm so confused why I'm getting directx 8.1 error.

Comment: It's not a dupe of that.