# Adobe Digital Editions 4.5 is already running

Tags: wine, adobe-digital-editions

I'm trying to install ADE in Ubuntu 16.04 32 bit.

First I run:  `wine ~/Downloads/ADE_4.5_Installer.exe` but got an error

Second, I tried to install with `winetricks`, go to install an application option and select `Adobe Digital Editions 4.5` and at the end, it shows the error.

In both methods, it shows the same error:

[image]

Program Error Detail shows:

```
Unhandled exception: page fault on read access to 0x00000000 in 32-bit code (0x10001559).
Register dump:
 CS:0073 SS:007b DS:007b ES:007b FS:0033 GS:003b
 EIP:10001559 ESP:0033fcf8 EBP:004072f0 EFLAGS:00210202(  R- --  I   - - - )
 EAX:00000000 EBX:00000000 ECX:0043a020 EDX:00000000
 ESI:00157598 EDI:00422ec0
Stack dump:
0x0033fcf8:  004037d7 00000001 00000000 00403b05
0x0033fd08:  00000001 7b4604d0 0042a400 00429000
0x0033fd18:  00000000 00000001 9d76a436 00429000
0x0033fd28:  0040351d 004035b3 0033fed8 00000000
0x0033fd38:  7b639000 7b639000 00000000 00000020
0x0033fd48:  00000000 00429015 00000000 00000000
Backtrace:
=>0 0x10001559 in system (+0x1559) (0x004072f0)
0x10001559: testl   %eax,0x0(%eax)
Modules:
Module  Address         Debug info  Name (96 modules)
PE    400000-  43a000   Deferred        ade_4.5_installer
PE  10000000-10006000   Export          system
ELF 7ac00000-7ac84000   Deferred        riched20<elf>
  \-PE  7ac10000-7ac84000   \               riched20
ELF 7b400000-7b7ea000   Deferred        kernel32<elf>
  \-PE  7b410000-7b7ea000   \               kernel32
ELF 7bc00000-7bcfa000   Deferred        ntdll<elf>
  \-PE  7bc10000-7bcfa000   \               ntdll
ELF 7c000000-7c004000   Deferred        <wine-loader>
ELF 7d825000-7d82e000   Deferred        libffi.so.6
ELF 7d82e000-7d8ba000   Deferred        libgmp.so.10
ELF 7d8ba000-7d8ef000   Deferred        libhogweed.so.4
ELF 7d8ef000-7d92c000   Deferred        libnettle.so.6
ELF 7d92c000-7d941000   Deferred        libtasn1.so.6
ELF 7d941000-7d975000   Deferred        libidn.so.11
ELF 7d975000-7d9d6000   Deferred        libp11-kit.so.0
ELF 7d9d6000-7db2e000   Deferred        libgnutls.so.30
ELF 7db4f000-7db89000   Deferred        ws2_32<elf>
  \-PE  7db60000-7db89000   \               ws2_32
ELF 7db89000-7dbb3000   Deferred        iphlpapi<elf>
  \-PE  7db90000-7dbb3000   \               iphlpapi
ELF 7dbb3000-7dbe2000   Deferred        netapi32<elf>
  \-PE  7dbc0000-7dbe2000   \               netapi32
ELF 7dbe2000-7dc16000   Deferred        secur32<elf>
  \-PE  7dbf0000-7dc16000   \               secur32
ELF 7dc16000-7dc5c000   Deferred        usp10<elf>
  \-PE  7dc20000-7dc5c000   \               usp10
ELF 7dca2000-7dcb6000   Deferred        shfolder<elf>
  \-PE  7dcb0000-7dcb6000   \               shfolder
ELF 7dcb6000-7dd14000   Deferred        oleacc<elf>
  \-PE  7dcc0000-7dd14000   \               oleacc
ELF 7dd14000-7dd2b000   Deferred        dwmapi<elf>
  \-PE  7dd20000-7dd2b000   \               dwmapi
ELF 7dd2b000-7de5d000   Deferred        oleaut32<elf>
  \-PE  7dd40000-7de5d000   \               oleaut32
ELF 7de5d000-7de85000   Deferred        propsys<elf>
  \-PE  7de60000-7de85000   \               propsys
ELF 7de85000-7de9f000   Deferred        apphelp<elf>
  \-PE  7de90000-7de9f000   \               apphelp
ELF 7de9f000-7df0c000   Deferred        setupapi<elf>
  \-PE  7deb0000-7df0c000   \               setupapi
ELF 7df0c000-7df44000   Deferred        uxtheme<elf>
  \-PE  7df10000-7df44000   \               uxtheme
ELF 7df44000-7df4b000   Deferred        libxfixes.so.3
ELF 7df4b000-7df57000   Deferred        libxcursor.so.1
ELF 7df57000-7df6a000   Deferred        libxi.so.6
ELF 7df6a000-7df6e000   Deferred        libxcomposite.so.1
ELF 7df6e000-7df7b000   Deferred        libxrandr.so.2
ELF 7df7b000-7df87000   Deferred        libxrender.so.1
ELF 7df87000-7df8e000   Deferred        libxxf86vm.so.1
ELF 7df8e000-7df92000   Deferred        libxinerama.so.1
ELF 7df92000-7df99000   Deferred        libxdmcp.so.6
ELF 7df99000-7df9d000   Deferred        libxau.so.6
ELF 7df9d000-7dfc3000   Deferred        libxcb.so.1
ELF 7dfc3000-7e10e000   Deferred        libx11.so.6
ELF 7e10e000-7e123000   Deferred        libxext.so.6
ELF 7e12a000-7e142000   Deferred        userenv<elf>
  \-PE  7e130000-7e142000   \               userenv
ELF 7e144000-7e1d2000   Deferred        winex11<elf>
  \-PE  7e150000-7e1d2000   \               winex11
ELF 7e1d2000-7e1f6000   Deferred        imm32<elf>
  \-PE  7e1e0000-7e1f6000   \               imm32
ELF 7e27d000-7e2a7000   Deferred        libexpat.so.1
ELF 7e2a7000-7e2f0000   Deferred        libfontconfig.so.1
ELF 7e2f0000-7e31b000   Deferred        libpng12.so.0
ELF 7e31b000-7e336000   Deferred        libz.so.1
ELF 7e336000-7e3e6000   Deferred        libfreetype.so.6
ELF 7e407000-7e488000   Deferred        rpcrt4<elf>
  \-PE  7e410000-7e488000   \               rpcrt4
ELF 7e488000-7e5e3000   Deferred        ole32<elf>
  \-PE  7e4a0000-7e5e3000   \               ole32
ELF 7e5e3000-7e702000   Deferred        comctl32<elf>
  \-PE  7e5f0000-7e702000   \               comctl32
ELF 7e702000-7e778000   Deferred        shlwapi<elf>
  \-PE  7e710000-7e778000   \               shlwapi
ELF 7e778000-7e9c8000   Deferred        shell32<elf>
  \-PE  7e790000-7e9c8000   \               shell32
ELF 7e9c8000-7ea40000   Deferred        advapi32<elf>
  \-PE  7e9e0000-7ea40000   \               advapi32
ELF 7ea40000-7eb6f000   Deferred        gdi32<elf>
  \-PE  7ea50000-7eb6f000   \               gdi32
ELF 7eb6f000-7ed4f000   Deferred        user32<elf>
  \-PE  7eb80000-7ed4f000   \               user32
ELF 7ed4f000-7ed62000   Deferred        libnss_files.so.2
ELF 7ed62000-7ed6f000   Deferred        libnss_nis.so.2
ELF 7ed6f000-7ed8a000   Deferred        libnsl.so.1
ELF 7ef8a000-7efdf000   Deferred        libm.so.6
ELF 7efe6000-7f000000   Deferred        version<elf>
  \-PE  7eff0000-7f000000   \               version
ELF b7bd3000-b7bdd000   Deferred        libnss_compat.so.2
ELF b7bdf000-b7be4000   Deferred        libdl.so.2
ELF b7be4000-b7d9a000   Deferred        libc.so.6
ELF b7d9a000-b7db7000   Deferred        libpthread.so.0
ELF b7dd8000-b7f8f000   Dwarf           libwine.so.1
ELF b7f90000-b7fb5000   Deferred        ld-linux.so.2
ELF b7fb8000-b7fb9000   Deferred        [vdso].so
Threads:
process  tid      prio (all id:s are in hex)
00000008 AutoHotkey.exe
    00000009    0
0000000e services.exe
    00000030    0
    0000002d    0
    00000026    0
    0000001d    0
    00000015    0
    00000010    0
    0000000f    0
00000011 mscorsvw.exe
    0000001a    0
    00000019    0
    00000018    0
    00000012    0
00000013 explorer.exe
    0000002c    0
    0000002b    0
    00000025    0
    00000014    0
0000001b winedevice.exe
    00000022    0
    0000001f    0
    0000001e    0
    0000001c    0
00000023 plugplay.exe
    00000028    0
    00000027    0
    00000024    0
00000029 winedevice.exe
    00000033    0
    0000002f    0
    0000002e    0
    0000002a    0
00000034 (D) Y:\adobe_diged4\ADE_4.5_Installer.exe
    00000036    0
    00000035    0 <==
System information:
    Wine build: wine-3.0.3
    Platform: i386
    Version: Windows 5.1 (0)
    Host system: Linux
    Host version: 4.15.0-22-generic
```

I've tried PlayOnLinux, but same issue
At the end, it shows same as previous,

[image]

Here Program error details shows, along with previous error message,

```
System information:
    Wine build: wine-1.7.46 (Staging)
    Platform: i386
    Host system: Linux
    Host version: 4.15.0-22-generic
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does one install PlayOnLinux?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/233782/how-does-one-install-playonlinux) Please note that this application [is listed in PlayOnLinux](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XbQ5.png) database, so it should have [corresponding script](https://www.playonlinux.com/en/app-2671-Adobe_Digital_Editions_45.html).

Comment: @N0rbert Let me try using PlayOnLinux. But that question is regarding `installing Playonlinux`

Comment: @N0rbert - the same Wine error message is displayed when trying to install in Playonlinux

Answer (score 3):

You need to install using ADE 4.5.0, rather than any later version of 4.5.

From https://web.archive.org/web/20160309131635/https://adedownload.adobe.com/pub/adobe/digitaleditions/ADE_4.5_Installer.exe :

> This was an issue with the Adobe Digital Editions 4.5.6 installer from the Adobe website. I was able to avoid the problem by downgrading to the 4.5.0 installer

Additionally, from merpuis's comment here
https://www.playonlinux.com/en/app-2671-Adobe_Digital_Editions_45.html:

> I have been trying to get this running as well. Initially, after some fighting with it, I was able to get it to install using the script, but it gave me the error about already running. So I found the older version (4.5.0) and installed it instead.

In my case (Ubuntu 18.04) I then had a "serious error" after installing when running ADE, so it ultimately didn't work... but at least it did install.

Unfortunately, the filehippo link from the winehq page is dead and I've been unable to find a replacement download. I also don't have my copy anymore.

Note that neither of these are actually 4.5.0, so they'll give the already running error: https://filehippo.com/download_adobe_digital_editions/4.5.0.0.0/ and https://adedownload.adobe.com/pub/adobe/digitaleditions/ADE_4.5_Installer.exe.

Comment: The link now goes to a 404 page.

Comment: Updated answer. My answer should not be deleted as I believe it does provide an answer on how to proceed, even if a download link is not available.

Comment: The link that actually points to the working file is this one: https://web.archive.org/web/20160309131635/https://adedownload.adobe.com/pub/adobe/digitaleditions/ADE_4.5_Installer.exe