# Unable to Run Civilization VI in 18.04

Tags: 18.04, games, steam

I am using Proton on SteamPlay and installed the native Linux version of Civ VI. When launching it, I receive the error

> An unrecoverable error has occurred and Civilization VI cannot continue.

I have libopenal installed. When I try to run it from the command line I get the following:

[image: Screenshot of terminal output]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does one install PlayOnLinux?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/233782/how-does-one-install-playonlinux)

Comment: Why aren't you using the Steam client normally? I never ever needed to run games from command line. And I hope you didn't try to install the Windows version because that would be an absird considering that both Steam and Civ have native Linux versions.

Comment: @N0rbert I disagree with your dupe here. Reasons above. https://store.steampowered.com/app/289070/Sid_Meiers_Civilization_VI/ shows the system requirements for "SteamOS + Linux".

Comment: I am running the native Linux version, under Proton/Steam Play. I did try to run it normally, then ran from the command line to get more verbose feedback.

Comment: I believe it may simply be that my video card needs upgrading.

Comment: Regarding to the requirements you need: **SteamOS, Ubuntu 16.04 (64bit)** and **IMPORTANT NOTICE: ATI and INTEL chipsets are NOT supported to run Civilization VI LINUX.** i hope you get it to run anyway

Comment: Thanks Alex. I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 with an AMD Radeon, so the GPU is my problem, I'm sure. I've got the parts for a whole new system on it's way from newegg.com and in a couple of weeks I'll have an nVidia GTX 1050 ti 4GB card. That should solve this problem :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused about how you're launching the game. Why did you mention that you're using Proton but trying to run the native game? FYI Civ VI doesn't seem to work with wine, period. Including patches and custom distros of it, like Proton. So either you run the native version through steam or you don't run it at all, as far as my experience tells me.

Comment: It was just my video card that was unsupported. Everything is fine now.