# How to install wine-stable in ubuntu 19.10

Tags: wine, 19.10

I installed wine wine-5.6 on ubuntu 19.10 
but my kakaotalk messenger program is sometimes open but the most of the time it does not open
how should I install wine-stable on ubuntu 19.10? is it possible now?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does one install PlayOnLinux?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/233782/how-does-one-install-playonlinux)

Answer (score 0):

U can try installing kakaotalk messenger using [Play on linux](https://www.playonlinux.com/)  a little buggy sometimes but it work

Comment: ACTUALLY I used to use play on linux on 18.10. 
but after I upgrade to 19.10 noting works

Comment: u installed from the winehq official website  ? if not add the repo `sudo add-apt-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ eoan main' `&  for the stable branch  `sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable`