# RootsMagic7 worked with a hangup fault a few days ago on 20.04, but will not install or run with WINE 5.10 now

Tags: kubuntu, wine, 20.04, winetricks

RootsMagic7 is a geneology software package for Windows that was able to download and install a few days ago with Q4Wine.  It had a hang-up fault when trying to add a "fact" in the program.  This is the same problem described here: [RootsMagic 7.6.3 worked on Wine 4.0 Ubuntu 19.10 but not on Wine 5.0 Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/q/1233212/1092350)

I followed the instructions he said was a fix from WineHQ here:  https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu

This included the following steps:

1. removed the Wine and dependent packages including Q4Wine, Winetricks, and PlayonLinux
2. allowing 32 bit architecture `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386`
3. downloading the repository key `wget -O - https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key | sudo apt-key add -`
4. adding the repository `sudo add-apt-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ focal main'`
5. update the packages `sudo apt update`
6. install the package `sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable`
7. allow raw IP packages `dpkg-reconfigure wine-<branch>-amd64 wine-<branch> wine-<branch>-i386`

RootsMagic7 would not even open.  Tried installing Q4Wine, Winetricks, and PlayonLinux.  Tried reinstalling RootsMagic7 and now it will not even install with Q4Wine.  **Any ideas other than building a bi-arch Wine?**  Here are the instructions to build a dual architecture sandbox for Wine: https://wiki.winehq.org/Building_Biarch_Wine_On_Ubuntu

Wine version is now 5.10 instead of 5.7 in the answer given at the first hyperlink.

My system info: Operating System:
Kubuntu 20.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.18.5
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.68.0
Qt Version: 5.12.8
Kernel Version: 5.4.0-37-generic
OS Type: 64-bit
Processors: 4 × AMD Ryzen 3 3200G with Radeon Vega Graphics
Memory: 62.8 GiB of RAM

The window for "add fact" is frozen after selecting a type of fact to add.  All of the fact types disappear and the window freezes.  All of the other buttons work on the frozen window, except "cancel" and the program is stuck.  The system must be rebooted to get it to close.

[image: Frozen Window]

Maybe this is causing the problem, but I don't know how to fix it.

[image: unsecure repository]

Comment: I reverted back to Wine version 5.0 and RootsMagic7 is now installed but still hanging up when you "add a fact" to an individual record.  Not sure how to troubleshoot this fault.

Answer (score 0):

I installed the [WineHQ repo][1]https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu

During the upgrade from Ubuntu 19.10 to 20.04, I had this exact error.  On Ubuntu 20.04 wine version 5.0 this is now resolved.  Wine installed by `sudo apt-get install wine` and RootsMagic by `wine ~/Downloads/RM7Setup.exe`

Previously,
I used the development branch (wine installed by `sudo apt-get install winehq-devel`) to resolve issue.  This broke other applications, ie. GedSite 3.06 for which I use a dotnet 4.7.1 wine environment, somewhere between wine version 5.7 and 5.12.  Every time wine version updates, I find the applications have to refresh `~/.wine` (usually takes a few seconds longer than normal).  Hope that helps.

Comment: I made a backup of `~/.wine` and `~/winedotnet45` folders.  I use other genealogy applications and wanted to prevent possible failure disrupting other working applications.  The other applications also worked except some had to be initiated from `desktop` folder the first time and then re-added to favourites.

Comment: To un-freeze, I used the System Monitor and selected `RootsMagic.exe` and ended the process.

Comment: Folder `~/winedotnet45` is not used by RootsMagic.

Comment: PlayOnLinux did not work for RootsMagic and wine stable branch did not work for me.

Comment: It is not working for me.  Maybe I have some bad packages with all the switching between versions looking for a fix.  I have just been "remove"-ing  all wine applications, with Discover, then reinstalling either with terminal commands or the Discover program.  I think I have a clean install of Wine 5.0 and need to run Q4 Wine to install RootsMagic.  It still hangs up when trying to "add a fact".  I AM using Kubuntu 20.04.  I wonder if that makes a difference.

Comment: @Burndoggiest I put as much information as I could in the hopes it would help.  I am using `https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/focal main`, see (https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu) as my wine repo.  Otherwise, I might have to agree that there may be differences between Kubuntu 20.04 and Ubuntu 20.04.  I did not remove the repo when I did `sudo apt-get install wine`.  It took out my upgrades to wine 5.12 and reverted to a working wine 5.0.  I have RootsMagic 7.6.3 working with the install procedure I described.

Answer (score 0):

I followed these instructions to get Wine updated, on my Kubuntu 20.04 install:

[How to Install Wine 5.12 in Ubuntu 20.04 / Linux Mint 20](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2020/07/onstall-wine-5-12-ubuntu-20-04-linux-mint-20/)

After following the instructions, I launched my previous RootsMagic 7 Wine, and it updated, and successfully updated mono and gecko... and now it works.

Comment: Hey Matteo! Please don't provide links to other website. Try quoting the content of the website. (Use the [edit] feature to edit your answer)

Comment: I still can't get this to work.  Trying on a desktop with Ubuntu 20.04 and a laptop with Kubuntu 20.04.

Comment: I am getting this error when installing RootsMagic7 on Ubuntu from command terminal.  "0036:err:winediag:SECUR32_initNTLMSP ntlm_auth was not found or is outdated. Make sure that ntlm_auth >= 3.0.25 is in your path. Usually, you can find it in the winbind package of your distribution."

Comment: HA!  I got it to work on the laptop with Kubuntu.  Deleted the old listing of RM7 and reinstalled via command terminal.  Then followed Wine update process to 5.12. It went through update process for mono and gecko and now RM7 works.