# HOW INSTALL WARCRAFT 3 ON UBUNTU 18.04

Tags: 18.04, wine, games, winetricks, vulkan

I know there is already lots of subjects about it... but i try everything and nothing work for me.
Can you help me plz to play again at my favorit game ;)
i try like 10 times to install with différents way :

```
1. I try with and without vulkan-drivers ... I need it?
2. Install DVXK ( i try version 1.5,1.6,1.4.6) i need it ? what is good version ?
3. I try wine-staging 5.8 wine-stable 5.0 Still work with this last versions ? i don't know how install older version like 4.2?
4. I try to install with winetricks : ie8, corefont, vcrun2005... its useful?
```

Thx for help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does one install PlayOnLinux?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/233782/how-does-one-install-playonlinux)

Comment: Thx but play on linux is not updated since long time. Dont working for it

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to install PlayOnLinux with

```
sudo apt-get install playonlinux

cd ~/Downloads
wget https://www.playonlinux.com/script_files/PlayOnLinux/4.3.4/PlayOnLinux_4.3.4.deb
sudo apt-get install wine:i386 ./PlayOnLinux_4.3.4.deb
```

and try installation from it:

> [image: PlayOnLinux]

Comment: i will try it but i believe POL installation doesn't work to play online since there is battlenet launcher