# error 1904: Module C: \windows\syswow64\msxml3.dll failed to register. HRESULT-2147220473. Contact your support personnel

Tags: software-installation, wine

While installing E-sword with wine in Ubuntu 20.10 I get "error 1904: Module C: \windows\syswow64\msxml3.dll failed to register. HRESULT-2147220473. Contact your support personnel."

I have searched for fixes and can't find one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does one install PlayOnLinux?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/233782/how-does-one-install-playonlinux) - it has E-Sword listed with recipe.