# sudo wine64 Wow.exe -opengl results in black screen and World of Warcraft cursor

Tags: 20.04, wine, opengl, winetricks

I've installed wine 5.21 Staging, corefonts with winetricks, changed the WTF config file to use opengl, I enabled EAX in winecfg (can't enable VAPPI because it's grayed out). I read in the guide https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-play-world-of-warcraft-on-linux-with-wine that it should take several minutes to boot up the screen and run badly but then you should be able to enable DX9 instead of DX11, but it just stays black and the only way to get out is to hit escape twice.

If I use the launcher and hit play, the same thing happens. I've tried these commands

```
sudo wine 'World of Warcraft Launcher.exe'
sudo wine 'Wow.exe'
sudo wine64 'World of Warcraft Launcher.exe'
sudo wine64 'Wow.exe'
sudo wine 'World of Warcraft Launcher.exe' -opengl
sudo wine 'Wow.exe' -opengl
sudo wine64 'World of Warcraft Launcher.exe' -opengl
sudo wine64 'Wow.exe' -opengl
```

And no matter what I do, it just gets stuck on the black screen with the World of Warcraft gauntlet cursor until I hit escape twice.

I'm using a 64 bit wine prefix @ /home/username/.wine/drive_c/
Wow.exe is @ 'Program Files (x86)'/'World of Warcraft'/*retail*/
World of Warcraft Launcher.exe is @ 'Program Files (x86)'/'World of Warcraft'/

Comment: My apologies, I've updated the tag to 20.04

Comment: I'm not familiar with what you're trying to do, but your description has you using `sudo` for everything... the instructions say `sudo` is required for specific tasks and normal for others (use `sudo` only when you need elevated privileges)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does one install PlayOnLinux?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/233782/how-does-one-install-playonlinux)