# How to install Amazon free Kindle app on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, wine, playonlinux

I can find links to install Amazon Kindle on Ubuntu 14 and 18, but these do not work for 16.04. I assume I have to install the latest Amazon Kindle free app for PC first.

I have Wine (`1:1.6.2-0ubuntu14.2`) and PlayOnLinux installed.
I have Windows 7 on another drive but do not want to boot that and spend time there just to read an ebook.

Apparently I can install the Kindle app through PlayOnLinux but I will have to upgrade to 18.04 LtS soon. Would the app still work or have to be installed again for 18.04 ?

Comment: First 16.04 is EOL in April of this year so I would recommend an upgrade. Second have you looked to see if wine supports this app?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does one install PlayOnLinux?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/233782/how-does-one-install-playonlinux) . And then install Kindle app from PlayOnLinux, they have a wizard for it.

Comment: i have PlayOnLinux installed frum the 16.04 repository.

Comment: @David yes i was going to upgrade finally to 20.04 so would    the Kindle app still work or have to be reinstalled?