# How to install wine with 32 bit architecture on Ubuntu Linux 5.8.0-43-generic

Tags: apt, wine, 64-bit, 32-bit

**1) Could someone provide a definitive answer please on how to install wine with 32 bit architecture and how to successfully launch ADE on my version of linux please? Previous tutorials say install wine 1.4 but the repositories are either outdated packages or can't be located...**

**2) Also, if terminal throws the error that it's an unsecure repository, I try --allow authenticated but the update still gets refused by default. How can this be solved?**

I've tried previous answers to questions on here and video tutorials, nothing seems to be relevant to what I'm attempting and on my fresh install of the newest Ubuntu Linux 5.8.0-43-generic.

I have an account on ebooks.com to read books on the computer, it only has Adobe Digital Editions in windows and mac. So after installing wine and winetricks but didn't know it needed 32 bit architecture exclusively so ADE would not launch. Wine executed the set up file but not the installed ADE.

Comment: 5.8 is a kernel not a Ubuntu version. I can GUESS the version is 20.04 or 20.10 by the kernel but the actual version may help get you an answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does one install PlayOnLinux?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/233782/how-does-one-install-playonlinux) ADE 4.5 is listed in PoL.

Comment: Right yes it is Ubuntu 20.04.2 thank you.