# How to install Chessbase on Linux

Tags: windows, wine

I have tried installing Chessbase 13 through 16 on Ubuntu 20.04(It was accidentally mentioned as Linux), but something or the other has broken. Can someone guide me through the process? Chessbase 13 is the closest I got something to work, but the board and the display was horribly broken.
I have installed Wine and winetricks, but so far I have not got anything to work.
Thank you for your time!

Edit: This is for people who don't know what Chessbase is.
ChessBase is a personal, stand-alone chess database that has become the standard throughout the world. https://shop.chessbase.com/en/products/chessbase_16_premium_package
I have tried installing it using Wine, but it has some weird errors. So anyone who has tried it successfully, please give some advice!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does one install PlayOnLinux?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/233782/how-does-one-install-playonlinux) Also look at https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=2793 .

Comment: guiverc - I have edited my question. My operating system is Ubuntu 20.04. Norbert-No, unfortunately I know that method, and it doesn't work for this specific software.

Comment: Wine is an emulator -- it doesn't necessarily mean it creates a perfect Windows environment for the application you want to install.  Only an actual Windows installation would give you that.  Looking at that link, it is published in November 2020, but it's for "Windows 7+".  It could mean that the software itself is a bit out of date.  Maybe you might have to go to an older version of Wine?  (Not sure if that would be compatible with Ubuntu 20.04, though.)

Comment: You can also instead use alternatives such as scid, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

Now there is a Linux program that will run Chessbase (and `.pgn`) files fine on Ubuntu.

It is Scidb and is a beautiful program. You download it from [sourceforge](http://scidb.sourceforge.net/) and there are several tweaks needed to install it.

But after that it runs great on Ubuntu 20.04 and 22.04. If interested I can post the tweaks here. It took me a lot of time to figure out the tweaks as the latest kernel upgrades borked it.

Answer (score 0):

Chessbase from 13 thru 18 not work on Wine. You need to change the setting of Wine and setup Windows 7. But and old version of Chessbase work fine try chessbase12.