# where is my game?

Tags: wine

I am trying to install battlenet and diablo 3 on Ubuntu (latest build and update)

I followed this video https://youtu.be/eefsL9K2w4k

and ran the following commands,

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 
sudo apt update

sudo apt install nvidia-driver-465

sudo apt install libvulkan1 libvulkan1:i386
```

reboot

```
sudo apt install wine

sudo apt install libgnutls30:i386 libldap-2.4-2:i386 libgpg-error0:i386 libsqlite3-0:i386

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:lutris-team/lutris

sudo apt update

sudo apt install lutris
```

The game and battle installed fine, but when I ran it it was unplayable (stuttering and lagging). So I rebooted and there is no sign I installed it?

when I open lutris to try again there is no sign I installed D3

Comment: Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll notice only supported releases of Ubuntu and flavors are on-topic for this site. For *jammy* indri [22.04] questions you'll need to use a development support site such as IRC (#ubuntu+next) or Ubuntu Forums, or wait until after release for this site [expected release date for Ubuntu 22.04 is 21 April 2022](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/jammy-jellyfish-release-schedule/23906)) when your question will be on-topic here.  *You didn't specify a release; but mention the latest build, which currently is jammy, thus off-topic; please be specific*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does one install PlayOnLinux?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/233782/how-does-one-install-playonlinux) as it is listed [there](https://www.playonlinux.com/en/app-1195-Diablo_III.html).

Comment: So after some investigation, I can get it to run from the lutris.net games diablo 3 route, but its so laggy I cant play it. I have looked around and someone changed the battlenet options to use the 32 bit version and it does indeed work a hell of a lot better but the graphics are shockingly horrible. thoughts?