# Wine Windows installer not working

Tags: wine

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.  I installed Wine 6.02 from https://www.winehq.org/  following the instructions there:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 
wget -nc https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key
sudo apt-key add winehq.key
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ focal main'
sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable
```

I tried then to install an exe using Wine Windows Program Loader.  Nothing seems to happen.  I tried with Q4Wine, same result.

I ran winecfg to see if there was anything there that might help.  I did not see anything.  I can not find Wine in an activities search.

Am I missing a dependency?  Something else?

thanks

Gary

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does one install PlayOnLinux?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/233782/how-does-one-install-playonlinux)

Comment: No-  I get the message Error in POL_Wine
Wine seems to have crashed

Comment: Could you please remove puzzles from your great and useful question? Which application are you trying to install? Why do you think that it is supported by Wine? Have you tried to find it on https://appdb.winehq.org/ ?

Comment: Program is Cookbook.exe.  It is not supported on wine, although there are a few references to it.

Comment: No-  same error as user 32674